# Testing Websocket server in Play

Tags: java, scala, testing, playframework, websocket

I'm developing a Play application in Scala with a WebSocket server.
This is The Controller:

```
class WebsocketServer {
  def subscribe() = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue]{ request => 
    out => <do something>
  }  
}
```

This is the corresponding route:

```
GET     /subscribe      @controllers.WebsocketServer.subscribe()
```

I've implemented a Websocket client with a Java class (using javax.websocket) to do some tests with Specs2. I run Play application through running(`FakeApplication()`). The client class tries to connect to the web socket server through the method `connect()`.

```
public void connect() {
   URI serverEndpointURI = URI.create("ws://localhost:9000/subscribe"); 
   try {
     WebSocketContainer c = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
     c.connectToServer(this, serverEndpointURI);
   } catch (Exception e){
   throw new RuntimeException(e);        
  }
}
```

But when I try to connect I have the following error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Is it possible to connect my Java Websocket client to my web socket controller in `FakeApplication()`? Is the URI correct? Is 9000 the default port also for FakeApplication?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the test server as actually running? And not just the `FakeApplication`?

Comment: I solved the problem by using 'new WithServer(app = FakeApplication(), port = 3333)'